# Why is $1/z$ analytic at infinity?

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

I was given this proof:

Let $w(z)=1/z$, so $w$ maps origin to inifinity and infinity to origin.

Consider $f(z) = z$. It has no singularities in finite $z$-plane.

So $f(w) = 1/w$ has a pole at the origin of $w$-plane, which is at infinity in the $z$-plane.

$f(z)=1/z$ has a pole at origin.

So $f(w) = w$ is analytic at $w=0$.

Therefore $1/z$ is analytic at infinity.

I do not understand this proof at all!

Comment: Basically, it's just saying that the function $f(z) = \frac{1}{z}$ is analytic at infinity for pretty much the same reason that the function $g(z) = z$ is analytic at 0.

Comment: Recapitulate what it means that a function, call it $f$, is analytic at $\infty$. Plug $f(z) = 1/z$ into the definition.

Comment: This [question-and-answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/311701/137524) from 2013 may provide some insight.